# How to log two Crashlytics Exceptions at a time

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm using Crashlytics and would like to send 128 KB of data up to the cloud using logException. Since Crashlytics has a max of 64 KB / exception, I call logException twice with different throwable instances. However, when restarting the app, only the first exception shows up on the Crashlytics Dashboard.

Is it possible to log multiple exceptions with Crashlytics to send over?
I understand Crashlytics' limit is 64 KB / exception and it stores a max of 8 exceptions at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is Zubair from Fabric/Firebase. You can log multiple exceptions with crashlytics and list of each exception max size is 64KB and exception limit/max is around 8 exceptions at a time.

Why only the first exception shows up on the Crashlytics Dashboard? - My hunch is that you might me reaching the limit of max exceptions so try limiting the exception to 6 and see, if resolves issue.